# $f(x)=\sin(x)\in H_{0}^{1}(\Omega)$ with $\Omega=(0,\pi)$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

We know that $f\in C^{\infty}(0,\pi)$ and $f(0)=f(\pi)=0$. But $supp\ f=[0,\pi]$. From the definition, $H_{0}^{1}(0,\pi)$ is the clusear of $C_{0}^{\infty}(0,\pi)$ in $H^{1}(0,\pi)$. Since, $f$ is not defined outside $(0,\pi)$ there is not any point outside the support on which $f$ vanish. So how we can say $f\in H_{0}^{1}(0,\pi)$?

Answer (score 2):

For $\epsilon>0$ small define $\phi_\epsilon(x)=\max(\sin x-\sin\epsilon,0)$, $0<x<\pi$. The support of $\phi_\epsilon$ is $[\epsilon,\pi-\epsilon]$. Its (weak) derivative is
$$
\phi_\epsilon'(x)=\begin{cases}
0 & 0<x<\epsilon\\
\cos x & \epsilon \le x\le\pi-\epsilon\\
0 & \pi-\epsilon<x<\pi
\end{cases}
$$
It is easy to see that $\phi_\epsilon\in H_0^1(0\,\pi)$ and
$$
\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\|\sin x-\phi_\epsilon(x)\|_{H^1}=0.
$$

Comment: Thank you very much @Julián Aguirre. But for each $\epsilon$, $\phi'_{\epsilon}$ is not continuous at $x=\epsilon$. I mean that $\phi_{\epsilon}$ is not in $C_{0}^{\infty}(0,\pi)$ or even in $C_{0}^{1}(0,\pi)$.

Comment: But it is in $L^2$.

Comment: Yes, of course. But what happens for the definition? We have to find $C^{\infty}$  molifiers.

Comment: Well, there are other equivalent definitions.

Comment: $H_0^1$ is  a closed subspace of $H^1$. If a sequence in $H_0^1$ converges in the $H^1$ norm, then its limit is in $H_0^1$. All is needed is to show that each $\phi_\epsilon$ is in fact in $H^1_0$. This can be done by convolution with a compactly supported approximation of the identity.

Comment: Thank you very much.